# Replication from Sybase SQL Anywhere to MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, replication, sqlanywhere, data-synchronization, sybase-asa

I am trying to replicate or synchronize data between Sybase SQL Anywhere database with MSSQL db.
I tried Proxy Table in SQLA and insert query is working fine. But for actual replication we need update and delete. For that I used INNER JOIN remote database with SQLA db, but it shows error

> update operation attempted on non-updatable remote query

. My Update query is below:

```
UPDATE Test
SET ID = S.accno, Name = S.particulars
FROM "DBA"."acc_ledgers" S
WHERE S.accno <> Test.ID
```

Update query on remote mssql database is working fine if no join or subquery is used. But when I join the SQLA table it gives error.

What is the problem in this? Can you suggest any solution or alternatives?

Thank you

Comment: Using `NOLOCK` against a table from want to retreive rows from for an `UPDATE` seems like a very poor choice. Why are you using `NOLOCK` there?

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake. Updated the question with new query. @Larnu